# In Oracle execution time for finding a data inside comma seperated column taking too long

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-apex

I am trying to find out if the list of data is in comma separated column. I have a code `select * from my_table where  (regexp_substr ( listcolumn, '[^,]+', 1, level ) in ('a','d')) connect by level <= regexp_count(listcolumn, ',') + 1;`  and table with a lot data. The problem is it works for small data table but  it is taking too much time to execute for a lot a table with a lot of data. I am not expert in database. so can you please help to how to resolve this problem. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Comma delimited strings in a column is a poor design choice. Consider creating a child table to hold your list items and go relational.

Answer (score 1):

Don't split the string, look for a sub-string match (with the surrounding delimiters so that you match entire terms):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   my_table
WHERE  ',' || listcolumn || ',' LIKE '%,' || 'a' || ',%'
OR     ',' || listcolumn || ',' LIKE '%,' || 'd' || ',%';
```